# Is it possible to see errors when executing a script inside a script?

Tags: linux, command-line, console

I have the files my1.sh and my2.sh.

my1.sh:

```
.... do something
./my2.sh
```

my2.sh:

```
.... do something else
```

Now my problem is that if any command (like or example a ntfsclone) fails in my2.sh I get no error message printed on screen....nothing regardless what I try in my2.sh.

So my question is what do I need to do in regards to my2.sh in order to get the error messages of its content shown on screen?

Answer (score 2):

Check again. According to what you wrote in your question, when you executed `./my2.sh` from within `my1.sh`, you did not redirect error output anywhere (using `2>somewhere`) which means it will stay exactly where it was. That means that you should absolutely get error output from `./my2.sh` going to exactly the same place the error output from `./mh1.sh` is going.

To test, try inserting this in `my1.sh`:

```
echo "Test error output from my1.sh" >&2
```

and inserting this near the beginning of `my2.sh`:

```
echo "Test error output from my2.sh" >&2
```

My guess is that you will either get both lines of output (in which case there is no problem) or neither (in which case the reason you are not getting error output is that error output is redirected somewhere else in `my1.sh` and has nothing to do with `my2.sh`).

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing the following at the top of each script for debugging feedback from them.

```
set -x
```

You can also type this directly in to the cli and it will do the same thing, just remember set +x when finished to disable it.

```
set +x
```